# Pass json object to Spring mvc controller using Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass simple JSON object to Spring MVC controller and getting error as “NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - https://my_url.html”

I am using Spring 3.2.10, jquery 1.6 and com.googlecode.json-simple 1.1.1 libraries. Follow I post my code,

JSP

```
function myTestFunction(year){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                
            url: "my_url.html",
            data: "{\"testName\": \"MyName\"}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            mimeType: "application/json",
            success: function(response){
                console.log("SUCCESS: " + response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("Error " + e);
            }
        });
```

Controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/my_url.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void myTestMethod(@RequestBody MyInfo myInfo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
// my code
 }
```

MyInfo class

```
    public class MyInfo {    
        private String testName;

        public MyInfo () {
        }   

        public MyInfo (String testName) {
            this.testName = testName;
        }

        public String getTestName() {
            return testName;
        }

        public void setTestName(String testName) {
            this.testName = testName;
        }
}
```

I have tried with several options by adding `dataType: 'json'` and sending object using `JSON.stringify` But didn't work for me.
And also I already put the `“<mvc:annotation-driven />”` tag in my spring configuration file.  What am I miss or doing incorrectly ?

Comment: When you make Ajax call, data  value is a string, try pass a json, for example: {key:value}

Comment: I have tried 'JSON.stringify' also, Did I miss any configuration in project?

Answer (score 1):

Your request and mapping are OK.

The error you mentioned can occur when a converter attempts to convert the HTTP request to JAVA object. You mentioned that you are using a *json-simple* library. Spring MVC expects *jackson* libraries on the classpath, so this can very well be your issue.

Try adding jackson libraries to your project. If using maven, for spring 3.2 the following should be a proper dependency, if you're using a different build system, simply download from maven repository, but also check for the transitive dependencies (you'll notice them listed inside the maven file in the jar archive)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.stringify. The ajax call will look like

function myTestFunction(year){

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",                
        url: "my_url.html",
        data: JSON.stringify({"testName": "MyName"}),
        contentType: "application/json",
        mimeType: "application/json",
        success: function(response){
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + response);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error " + e);
        }
    });
```